# Regex match including new line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex to grab everything between `"*"`:

```
str = "Donec sed odio dui. *Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut*"
str.match(/\*(.*)\*/)[1]
```

I want the match to be able to include newline characters. How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll want to use the `m` option which allows the dot to match new lines:

```
Donec sed odio dui. *Nullam id dolor id 
nibh ultricies vehicula ut*
```

**regex** `str.match(/\*(.*)\*/m)[1]` Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/11u9TreEOL

Your expression will capture the text between the first and last `*` symbol, but if you want to capture all text between each set of `*` then you'd want to make the `.*` less greedy like

`str.match(/\*(.*?)\*/m)[1]` Live example http://www.rubular.com/r/rBLOnwy3By

Or you could tell it to simply match all non `*` characters like, note the `m` option is not needed as a new line character would be matched by a the negated `[^*]` character class:

`str.match(/\*([^*]*)\*/)[1]` Live example http://www.rubular.com/r/dhQzZ58ZzM

Answer (score 4):

Put the `m` modifier after the regex like `/\*(.*)\*/m`.

By the way, your regex can be improved to:

```
str[/(?<=\*).*(?=\*)/m]
```

Comment: Ok but when i do `str[/(?<=\*).*(?=\*)/m]` it say : nil

Comment: héhé nope, try it by yourself :
str[/(?<=\*).*(?=\*)/m] return nil

Comment: `str[/(?<=\*).*(?=\*)/m]` leads to 'nil' i have to remove the 'm'.
By the way, my computer is not broken...