# Parsing string with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to parse a string with Ruby to get a shorter string.

My string:

> ðŸ’Ž #btc\nUp signal on Poloniex\n+895%, buy vol. incr. by 2.78 BTC\n+1.66%, price: 0.00000949 BTC\nSignals: 2/7d\nMarket Cap: $8,632,464"}

I have tried:

```
longstring.scan(/\#(.*?)\\\/)

longstring[/\#(.*?)\\/,1]

longstring.slice(/\#(.*?)\\/,1)
```

... where `longstring` is the variable that holds the orginal string

The regex works in Rubular, but my Ruby script does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the expected result? BTW, how come you get a [match in Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/4OYkXxLQRx) if it does not find a match?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what?

Comment: Ok, I think you want [`longstring[/#(.*)/, 1]`](https://ideone.com/4HFF7m)

Comment: Doesnt work, means what the match is suppose to be "btc". Is not the output

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thats much closer, but im missing the first charecter "b"

Comment: What else can there be? Please add the actual requirements for the pattern that should match `btc`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/4HFF7m. No `b` is missing.

Comment: Wiktor you got my bad.  You had it all along!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match including new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614666/regex-match-including-new-line)

Comment: Kindly state your question. As you were asked before, what is your desired result? Please provide that by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember things like `\n` are not literal backslash-n, but instead a *newline* character. As such the `\\` in your regular expression is mistaken.

A better matcher is:

```
longstring[/\#(\w+)/]
```